# iOS can't set backgroundImage of UIButton

Tags: ios

I can't seem to make the system use the custom created button I have. I have the following declarations in the interface section of my .m file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *useLocationButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *useAddressButton;
```

Then I have the following for my init function

```
- (id)init
{
if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"TCMDirectionsViewController" bundle:nil]){

    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Get Directions"];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                target:self
                                                                                action:@selector(cancel:)];
    click = NO;
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:cancelItem];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebutton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
    UIImage *buttonImageHighlight = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebuttonHighlight.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];

    [[self useLocationButton] setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self useLocationButton] setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [[self useAddressButton] setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self useAddressButton] setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

return self;
}
```

When I run the app though the buttons are the default white buttons I created in interface builder.

Comment: Have you tried using the button styling code within `viewDidLoad`? (Chances are the button's themselves don't yet exist when you're attempting to change their properties.)

Comment: Are your IBOutlets connected in IB? Probably the setBackground messages are being sent to the properties, but there aren't connected in IB, so when you load the nib, it load default buttons, and backgrounds are being set to other buttons

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing back button background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448386/changing-back-button-background-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `init` method is called before the view is loaded, so the `useLocationButton` doesn't exist yet.

Put your view setup in the [`viewDidLoad`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) method of your `UIViewController` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebutton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
    UIImage *buttonImageHighlight = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebuttonHighlight.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];

    [[self useLocationButton] setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self useLocationButton] setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [[self useAddressButton] setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self useAddressButton] setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Also, make sure that your `IBOutlets` are actually connected. You might want to set a breakpoint to check if the references are valid.

Comment: awesome! I knew I was missing some minor detail. Thanks!